# Safari issue export leaflet map to PNG image

Tags: image, dictionary, safari, export, leaflet

When i am trying to export leaflet map into PNG image in safari browser it gives me below error message :

**SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18: An attempt was made to break through the security policy of the user agent.**

its working fine with chrome but issue with safari. Please suggest me sample code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please provide more information about the steps you are following to get that error?  Please provide [a minimal, complete, and verifiable example (link)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).